# Mysql, how to save the special character like ''?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to save the special charater like '', but i don'r know use what type to save the data ,except the blob type. But that's very bother me , cause i don't want to turn it balck when i get it from mysql .

At the Java Console I have the exception like this : Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x98'  .

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: string/text column should suffice. Make sure you use unicode encoding.

Comment: I use the utf-8 charset , and the column is enough to save .

Comment: In that case you need to append the line useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8 to your jdbc url.

Comment: @J.Joe: in this case, the problem is in your java environment. It can't handle that kissy face.

Comment: Java environment? What kind of problems?

Comment: @PiyushGupta I will try.thank you

Comment: @J.Joe one more thing your MySQL needs to be 5.5+ version and Adjust your columns like var1 varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL

Comment: @PiyushGupta it doesn't work.

Comment: i change the setting as you say , but it still doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I find the answer . @PiyushGupta you are right . but only change the column charset is not enought . you should set the charset when you create the database . then you change the column it does worked.

Comment: But , I find a bug . The mysql only can save the ☺ emoji , and others can't save . I don't know why .